# Domination number of $G$ and its complement

Tags: graph-theory

I have a question, if $G$ is a $k$-regular graph with $k <\frac{n-1}{2}$, moreover, $G$ and its complement have diameter equal to $2$ and girth $3$, is it true that the domination number of $G$ is greater than or equal to the domination  number of its complement? Some reference please.
Sorry for my bad english.